# Error en AJAX en envío de formulario con PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un problema con un formulario con ajax y php el cual espero puedan ayudarme a solucionar, les comento...

Al llenar el formulario este se anvía, pero en al formulario no pasa anda, creo que el ajax no detecta que se envió el formulario, y devuelve error. Lo noto porque degún el inspeccionar en el navegador, el ajax agrega la clase que debe agregar al formulario en caso de error al hacer submit. y la consola me arroja el error "500 Internal Server Error"

**este es el formulario:**

```
<form id="contactForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required data-error="debes ingresar tu nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required data-error="debes ingresar un correo electrónico válido" placeholder="Correo Electrónico">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message" cols="30" rows="5" required data-error="Escribe tu mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<button type="submit">Enviar Mensaje</button>
<div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

**este es el js:**

```
(function ($) {
"use strict"; // Start of use strict
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "¿Completaste el formulario correctamente?");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});


function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "assets/php/form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "¡Mensaje enviado!")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h4 text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "h4 text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

}(jQuery));

**y este es mi form-procces.php:**

```
<?php
$name  = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email  = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

$destino = "info@midominio.com"; // variable que almacena el correo al q se le envia el comentario
$cuerpo  = "<html lang='es'><table><tr><td>Nombre: </td><td>".$name."</td></tr><tr><td>Correo electrónico: </td><td>".$email."</td></tr><tr> <td>Mensaje: </td><td>".$message."</td></tr></table></html>"; // variable que almacena todas las variables de los campos..

$titulo = 'Contacto web | '.date("d-m-Y").' ';
$mensaje = $cuerpo;
$cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'From: Contacto web <info@midominio.com.>' . "\r\n";

mail($destino, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);?>
```

Supongo que algo le hace falta a mi php.

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: Error 500 desde el servidor indica que algo en tu codigo PHP esta generando un error. Puedes agregar `ini_set("display_errors","on"); error_reporting(0xffff);` al inicio para ver el error que ocurre.

Comment: Mira los log del servidor PHP que tengas. Debería darte más información. Ponlo aquí junto a tu pregunta ok?

Comment: seguramente el error esta en la funcion mail. quizas una posible causa es que si el largo del $cuerpo es > 70 tenes que hacer un wordwrap. 

$cuerpo  = wordwrap($cuerpo, 70, "\r\n");

Pero no estoy seguro si eso causa un crash en la app para causar un error 500.

Comment: De hecho agregúe la linea "error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');" y n olanza ningun error, tendría que probar  $cuerpo = wordwrap($cuerpo, 70, "\r\n");

Answer (score 0):

El `error 500` puede deberse a la `url` que le estás pasando a tu `ajax` y que no esté encontrando tu archivo `php`

```js
$.ajax({
    //Esta ruta indica que assets está dentro de tu carpeta donde tienes el ajax
    //js/
    //├─┬─assets/
    //│ └┬─php/
    //│  └form-process.php
    //└─tuJS.js
    url: "assets/php/form-process.php"
});

$.ajax({
    //Esta ruta indica que assets se encuentra en la raíz de la pagina web actual
    url: "/assets/php/form-process.php"
});

$.ajax({
    //Esta ruta indica que assets está un nivel arriba de la ruta actual
    //public_html/
    //├┬─assets/
    //│└┬─php/
    //│ └──form-process.php
    //└┬─js/
    // └──tuJS.js
    url: "../assets/php/form-process.php"
});
```

Comment: De hecho el archivo lo encuentra, porque envía el mensaje al correo elecrónico, en envío se completa, me falta solucionar que el formulario me complete la parte del susses: "function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "¡Mensaje enviado!")
}"

Comment: si estás esperando el mensaje `success` como tienes en tu código, debes de poner un `echo('success')` en tu `php`. en tu código no aparece ese `echo`. o un `return`

Comment: gracias @alejandro00 Agregar echo('success') al final hace que aparezca el texto despues de enviar, pero no recorre el ajax como tal, ya que este no realiza el success del mismo, podría ser opción dejarlo como dices, pero tendría que agregar otra opción para que me limpie los datos del formulario luego de enviar, como sería esto en php?

Comment: el `form` después del evento `submit` se limpia solo, no entiendo si lo que quieres es limpiar tu `php`, pero el `html` debería de limpiarse después del evento `submit`, de echo refresca la página completa. Prueba removiendo tu función de `$("#contactForm")[0].reset();`.